# Sum of average reciprocal of which random variable converges to a Cauchy distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are independent identically distributed random variables with density $f$ even, continuous in $0$ and such that $f(0)>0$, then $$\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{X_1}+\dots + \frac{1}{X_n}\right)\xrightarrow{d}Z$$ With $Z$ a r.v. with Cauchy distribution.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution

Comment: As @Lost1 said in a deleted answer, having each $X_i$ having independent standard Cauchy distributions will give this result, as their reciprocals also have standard Cauchy distributions as does the average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Lévy's continuity theorem it's enough to prove that $\left(\varphi_{1/X_1}(t/n)\right)^n \rightarrow e^{-a|t|}$, with $\varphi_X(t):=\mathbb E^X\left[e^{itX}\right]$.

It is a well-known fact that if $(c_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a complex succession with limit $c$ then:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\left(1+c_n/n\right)^n=e^c.
$$

In this case $c_n=n\left(\varphi_{1/X_1}(t/n)-1\right)=n \mathbb  E^{1/X_1}[e^{(it)/(nX_1)}-1]$. Because $f$ is even:
$$
c_n=n\mathbb E^{1/X_1}[\cos(t/(nX_1))-1].
$$
Then:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to +\infty}c_n&=\lim_{n\to +\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}n\frac{\cos(tx/n)-1}{x^2}f(1/x) \ dx\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-n|t|(1-\cos(1/(ny)))f(ty) \ dy
\end{align}

with $y:=1/(tx)$.

If $\rho (y)=1-cos(1/y)$ and $\rho_n(y)=n\rho(ny)$ then $\int \rho=\int \rho_n =\pi$ and $\rho_n$ have masses that concentrate in $0$. So  $\lim_{n\to +\infty}c_n=-\pi f(0)|t|$ and we have the thesis.